# .npmrc permission denied every time I open the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, npmrc

I've been getting this annoying error everytime I open a new terminal window or tab saying:

`bash: /.npmrc: Permission denied`

And that is it, I have been trying to find a solution (unsuccessfully) for some time now. I've found that people had issue with other files but not with .npmrc. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 if it is of any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Which command in your bash startup files produces the error message? Also post how you configured your Terminal to start bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `sudo chown -Rv ${USER}:${USER} /.npmrc` ?

Comment: Incredible, it worked!!
But what could have caused it?

Comment: This is not so incredible, this is how unix file systems work. :)